# How to use a dynamic name for an imported image in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following code imports and displays an image `Image1001`.

```
import Image1001 from '../images/1001.jpg';
<img src={Image1001} alt="" />
```

The above code displays the image correctly. However I want to generate the image names dynamically. For example, 1001 is the ID that I get in the map function. So I am trying following {`Image${item.id}`} but it does not display the image. Here is the full code:

```
{
    list.map(item => (      
        <li key={item.id}>
            <img src={`Image${item.id}`} alt="" />
        </li>
        )
    )
}
```

I can see the following in the page source:

```
<img src="Image1001" alt="">
```

I think the problem is that it is adding **""**, that's why it is not working.

I have also tried following:

```
<img src={'Image' + item.id} alt="" />
```

It also gives same result.

So my question is, how to create dynamic Image names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a note: To the JS interpreter, `Image1001` is not a string, it's a variable. Passing the string `"Image1001"` is not the same as passing the variable.

If the source file paths are consistent you can just put the path to the jpg directly

```html
<img src={`../images/${item.id}.jpg`} alt="" />
```

You probably want to use a path relative to the root instead of the current file though in case this file gets moved. ie. start with `/` instead of `../` and give the path relative to the root directory.

See here for syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

---

Otherwise you can create a resource file and export an object that has strings as keys, and the images as values. That will let you index the object with strings.

```js
import image1001 from '../images/1001.jpg';
import image1002 from '../images/1002.jpg';
import image1003 from '../images/1003.jpg';

export const allImages = {
  image1001, // shorthand for image1001: image1001,
  image1002,                     
  image1003,
};
```

Usage:

```js
<img src={allImages[`image${item.id}`]} alt="" />
```

This is better if the image file paths are subject to change, since IDEs can generally auto update those import statements. But it requires a lot more setup to add images.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's best practice, but you don't actually need to import the image to use it, you should be able to do something like this, using `require` and the path to the image:

```
{
    list.map(item => (      
        <li key={item.id}>
            <img src={require(`../images/Image${item.id}.jpg`)}
 alt="" />
        </li>
        )
    )
}
```